# Python code efficiency

Tags: python, matrix

This program tests if a matrix is an identity matrix or not.

I have pasted my code beneath, and would like to know ways in which I can optimize the efficiency of this code. Also I am new to python programming, are there some built in functions that can solve the purpose too?

```
    def is_identity_matrix(test):
    if (test == []):
        return False
    i = 0
    while (i < len(test)):
        if (len(test[i]) == len(test)):
            j = 0
            while(j < len(test[i])):
                if (j != i):
                    if(test[i][j] != 0):
                        return False
                else:
                    if(test[i][j] != 1):
                        return False
                if(j == (len(test[i]) - 1)):
                    break
                j += 1
            if(i == (len(test) - 1)):
                break
            i += 1
        else:
            return False
    if(i == j and i == (len(test) - 1)):
        return True

# Test Cases:

matrix1 = [[1,0,0,0],
           [0,1,0,0],
           [0,0,1,0],
           [0,0,0,1]]
print is_identity_matrix(matrix1)
#>>>True

matrix2 = [[1,0,0],
           [0,1,0],
           [0,0,0]]

print is_identity_matrix(matrix2)
#>>>False

matrix3 = [[2,0,0],
           [0,2,0],
           [0,0,2]]

print is_identity_matrix(matrix3)
#>>>False

matrix4 = [[1,0,0,0],
           [0,1,1,0],
           [0,0,0,1]]

print is_identity_matrix(matrix4)
#>>>False

matrix5 = [[1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]]

print is_identity_matrix(matrix5)
#>>>False

matrix6 = [[1,0,0,0],  
           [0,1,0,2],  
           [0,0,1,0],  
           [0,0,0,1]]

print is_identity_matrix(matrix6)
#>>>False
```

Comment: One word: `numpy`.

Comment: or two, numpy and [identity](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.identity.html)

Comment: Do you **realy** need to work with matrices? If you do, should use numpy. If you are just coding to learn: `import this`

Comment: Sounds like a homework-type question to me.

Comment: @Aya it is :P But I wasn't satisfied with my code...

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
def is_identity_matrix(listoflist):
    return all(val == (x == y) 
        for y, row in enumerate(listoflist)  
            for x, val in enumerate(row))
```

(though, this does not check if the matrix is square, and it returns True for an empty list)

Explanation: Inside `all` we have a generator expression with nested loops where `val` loops over each value in the matrix. `x == y` evaluates to `True` on the diagonal and `False` elsewhere. In Python, `True == 1` and `False == 0`, so you can compare `val == (x == y)`. The parentheses are important: 
`val == x == y` would be a chained comparison equivalent to `val == x and x == y`

Comment: I think I needed to think through this one for about a full minute before deciding that it seems like it would work.  Ultimately, I think this deserves kudos (and an upvote) for being able to pull off a not-too-ugly 1-liner in pure python with short-circuiting behavior.

Comment: I think `val == 1 for ... for ... if x == y` would be clearer. I sometimes use booleans as integers too, but generally it's not very obvious.

Comment: @Janne Karila:
Hey can you help me understand what this code is doing? I would really really appreciate. This code is awesome- its clean :D

Comment: @delnan: but you also have to verify that `val == 0` where `x != y`! So in the end I'm not sure Janne's answer can really be improved.

Comment: @icecrime D'oh! You're right. I think `val == 1 if x == y else val == 0` is still competitive, but not obviously better.

Comment: Terrific... If I read all your Python answers, will I become a Python too? :)

Answer (score 6):

I'd use `numpy`:

```
(np.array(matrix1) == np.identity(len(matrix1))).all()
```

Of course, it'd be better if you were storing `matrix1` as a numpy array in the first place to avoid the conversion.

Comment: Hey Thank you! +1 I didn't know of numpy :)

Comment: @AbrarKhan -- It's not in the standard library, but it's a pretty common 3rd party extension because it is extremely useful.

Comment: Put `dtype=np.bool` in the call to `np.identity` for roughly twice the speed! (If the matrix is already a numpy array)

Answer (score 1):

Multiply by the all ones vector and check that the result is the same

Comment: There are many non-identity matrices that will pass this test.

Answer (score 1):

Check the size of your matrix, make sure it is n x n, then create an actual identity matrix using np.identity(n), then compare your matrix with the new one you created.

Answer (score 1):

```
def is_identity_matrix(test):
    if not test : return False
    le = len(test[0])
    for i,x in enumerate(test):
        if len(x) == le:
            if any(y!=1 if j==i else y!=0 for j,y in enumerate(x)):
                return False
        else:
            return False
    return True if len(test) == le else False
```

Comment: I don't understand your first line -- `if len(test)%2: return False`.  Why does the number of rows have to be odd?

Answer (score 0):

If speed is important you should probably look at Numpy, but in a situation where you can't use it or perhaps it isn't worth it to have the matrix as a Numpy array you could also use the following:

```
def is_identity(mat):
    for i, row in enumerate(mat):
        if any(row[:i]) or row[i]!=1 or any(row[i+1:]):
            return False
    return True
```

About 12x faster than the code of the currently accepted answer! For a matrix of 2000x2000 at least...

The above does not check the matrix dimensions, but you can easily add something like:

```
n = len(matrix)
if not all(len(row) == n for row in matrix):
    return False
```